# Visual Studio freezes on start

Tags: visual-studio-2015, suo

Every time I open Visual Studio 2015 Professional it freezes and I have to delete the `.suo` file to get it to work.

I know what the file is, but I don't know why Visual Studio is freezing. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: dis you try right click open as administrator?

Comment: Does this happen with a *specific* solution, or with all solutions?

Comment: Have you installed any extensions or add-ons recently?

Comment: You could open VisualStudio in SafeMode (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) and then navigate to the solution. If it does not freeze in safemode, then its possible an extension is freezing your VS.

Comment: It was an extension.... I have uninstalled extensions, one by one, until I found the faulty one: "NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015" :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the [Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d) extension. Unfortunately, reinstalling the extension didn't fix the issue. Only by removing it completely Visual Studio works accordingly. I've managed to install this extension from here: https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.2.0-rc/NuGet.Tools.2015.vsix  and now it works perfectly!
Thanks Szeki & Sosian for suggesting that it's an extension issue!